# C# OpenXML - generated xlsx file corrupted even from basic save as operation

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

Using OpenXML with C# to generate an excel file is creating a corrupted file. This occurs even in the most simple case of opening an existing file and saving it. The saved output is smaller than the input .xlsx file and causes an error message in Microsoft Excel and Excel on office 365, this error doesn't occur with open office excel. Both Microsoft Excel and office 365 can open the file but they display a message saying the file had to be repaired. Opening and resaving the file from Excel (365,MS or OpenOffice) the file size returns to normal and the error message doesn't occur. Any Idea how I can get openXML to output the correct filesize/file that isn't somehow corrupted.

This is the most basic code sample that has the issue.

```
SpreadsheetDocument immutableDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(templatePath, false);
        immutableDoc.SaveAs(outPath).Close();
```

Comment: Try replacing "Close" with "Dispose". If that doesn't work, try using [Open XML SDK Validator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-validate-a-word-processing-document) to check if there are any errors. Last, can you upload somewhere your input file (the "templatePath") so that I can try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Hi Mario changing close to dispose has fixed the issue, thank you so much :), I spent ages searching for a solution to this. It was occurring with every template .xlsx I tried btw.